# How to Read Request Input from Route?

Tags: laravel

Okay so i am having some trouble. I am trying to read the Input Values from the Post Form in Laravel. However i am getting a Method Not Allowed.

```
My Routes:

Route::get('/', function () {
    return View::make('pages/home');
});

Route::post('/summoner/data', function (Request $request) {
    return redirect()->url($request->region .'/'. $request->summonername);
});

Error:
[![Error I am getting][1]][1]
```

As you can see from above code i am trying to send my details to an Api. I am not sure if this is the best way of doing it though so i am open to suggestions. But at the moment i cannot read any Input Data from the Form.

Comment: Insert `dd($request)` before `return` line, what does it show?

Comment: Like this? Route::post('/summoner/data', function (Request $request) {
    dd($request);
    return redirect()->url($request->region .'/'. $request->summonername);
});  it still shows Method Not Allowed

Comment: It seems the problem is somewhere else. Can you post some more info please (full error message, code which calls this route).

Comment: I will update my question

Comment: if it is said Method Not Allowed then check your form that you are sending post request in right url.

Comment: Thats the think i am posting to the correct url

Comment: If Laravel says "Method Not Allowed" it means that you are using GET method in the form probably and not POST.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this assuming you already injected the `Request`

```
// Request is injected to the closure
Route::post('/summoner/data', function (Request $request) {

  // To see the whole POST body
  $bodyContent = $request->getContent();
  dd($bodyContent);

  // Get fullname input
  echo $request->get('fullname')

});
```